# Слово "крепостной" (крестьянин)

Tags: морфемика

В слове "крепостной" будем выделять корень "**крепостн**" или "крепост"? У Тихонова корень "**крепостн**", но я думаю, что корнем будет "**крепост**", потому что есть "за**крепощ**ение".

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с вами. Это очередные выдумки Тихонова. Тут дело не столько в словообразовании, сколько в ***подходе***. **Что** я имею в виду?

---

Принято считать, что **корень** - ***это общая часть родственных слов***. Если принять за чистую монету, что у некоторых прилагательных, стоящих первыми в словообразовательном ряду, мы не выделяем суффиксов, тогда придется пересматривать разбор многих слов, что приведет к большому количеству расхождений.

---

Взять даже слово "глубокий": у Тихонова здесь "ок" входит в корень, а у Потихи - нет, что, как я думаю, куда верней, поскольку родственных слов будет навалом.

---

Вернемся к нашему случаю. Слово "**крепостной**" (крестьянин) и правда будет **первообразным** прилагательным, однако у него имеется ряд родственных слов:

1)За**крепост**ить

2)Рас**крепост**ить

3)За**крепощ**ение

4)Рас**крепощ**ение

[image: Крепостной]

Думаю, что не нужно объяснять связь "**крепостного**" с "за**крепощ**ением". Эта связь актуальна в СРЯ и поэтому видна невооруженным глазом даже обывателю.
Во всех словах мы можем увидеть один и тот же чередующий корень - ***крепост/крепощ***, соответственно, в слове "**крепостной**" мы выделим корень "**крепост**"!

Comment: Скажите,  пожалуйста,  для какого учебного комплекса (1, 2 и 3)  какой словообразовательный словарь подходит.  Например,Тихонов – это для какого комплекса? И для какого комплекса даете свои объяснения вы?

Comment: @Sharon Потиха подходит для всех! Его словарь потому и называется "школьным". Тихонов - это не для школы вообще.

Comment: А как это проверить? Я считала, что Тихонов –  это самый школьный словарь. А для кого же он тогда? Читаю ответы Грамоты.ру, они ссылаются на Тихонова.

Comment: А при чем тут "Грамота. ру" и школьный словарь?

Comment: А что, они никак не связаны? У вас есть какие-нибудь точные сведения по этому вопросу? Важная тема.  При большом количестве словарей надо бы учитывать  учебный комплекс. И у Тихонова тоже школьный словарь (так называется).

Comment: Его словарь не для школы, для школы словари Тихонова не подходят.

Answer (score 1):

**Креп+ост+н+ой** - от слова **креп**ить или при**креп**лять, корень, очевидно, **креп**, по типу жаль/жало -> жалость -> жалостный. Крестьяне были прикреплены к земле как вещи-объекты, без права свободного переселения, юридически называлось это состояние "крепость". Земля же в свою очередь принадлежала феодалу - боярину, дворянину, позже помещику. Но термин крепость - не являлся единственно возможным словом для рассуждения по этой теме, так что нечего забор городить. Есть точная дата возникновения юр термина *крепостное право*, а значит и *крепостных-крепости* - **1649 год  Соборное Уложение полностью прикрепило крестьян к земле.** Можно сослаться на правление на Бориса Годунова, но там разница небольшая.

Слово **креп**ость также происходит от слова **креп**ить, с**креп**лять, с**креп**а - соединять, соединение ~ сделка - договор.

**СКРЕПА** -

> 3. перен. То, что скрепляет, соединяет, сплачивает.
> 4. Подпись, которой скрепляют какой-нибудь документ (офиц. канц.). Копия за скрепой секретаря. Ушаков.

**Скреплять/скрепить - совершенная форма от крепить**.

Слово КРЕПОСТНАЯ ГРАМОТА упоминается в [судебнике Ивана IV Грозного][3], однако всего 2 раза, более частое упоминание слов скрепление имеющее смысл что-то между договором и правом на владение - 5 раз:

> ...недельщику полтина и за **скрепление сделки** сторон... ст. 11

> ...он должен предстать перед боярином и дьяк должен подписать старую
> **крепостную грамоту**, а пошлины брать с человека по алтыну. ст.80

Однако, крестьяне не относились к крепости и была возможность перейти к другому хозяину самовольно, при уплане ПОЖИЛОГО:

> Вотчина - форма феодального землевладения, при которой владелец имеет право ее продать, отдать,
> обменять и т.п.
> Пожилое - налог, уплачиваемый крестьянином при переходе к другому владельцу в Юрьев день.

А вот КРЕПОСТНЫМИ крестьяне становятся в акте Соборного Уложения 1649, там очень много употребления слов крепость и крепостной.

У Даля: КРЕПкий->КРЕПость->КРЕПостной

> Крепость, крепковатость принадлежность, состоянье по знач. прил.
> Крепость, сила, мочь; защита; || стар. присяга, клятва; || запись,
> документ, свидетельство, выданное судебным местом на право владенья
> недвижною собиною; || укрепленное противу врагов, по военным правилам,
> место, твердыня. Не для пригожества, для крепости. В крепостных делах
> по крепостям, в некрепостных — по розыскам, т. е. разбираться; стар.
> Наука постройки крепостей, фортификация. Крепости берут осадою и
> приступом, либо вымаривают голодом. Крепостца ж. небольшая крепость,
> место, окруженное валом и рвом, вооруженное и снабженное всем нужным
> для защиты. Иногда употреб. и в других знач. Земля с крепостцою,
> твердый суглинок, нерыхлая. Человек с крепостцою, бережливый,
> скуповатый.

[**Мнение о прикреплении крестьян**](https://mse.msu.ru/history/21/book/text-21-02.pdf) - Ключевский.

> в конце XVI столетия правительство
> одною общей законодательной мерой изменило юридическое положение
> крестьян, отняв у них право выхода, **прикрепив** их к земле, и 2) вследствие
> этого **прикрепления** крестьяне попали в неволю к землевладельцам.

> Так как **первый указ, отменявший крестьянское право выхода, был
> издан**, когда государством правил **именем царя Федора шурин его Борис
> Годунов**, то на этого правителя падает вся ответственность за эти
> последствия: **он — первый виновник крепостного права, крепостник-учредитель**.

То есть **крепостной** или название или термин появившееся только при Борисе Годунове или позднее. До этого некоторые крестьяне были "прикрепленные к земле", но слов *крепостной* и *крепость* в смысле юр. статуса - не было.

> В истории несвободных состояний под
> *поземельным прикреплением крестьян* разумеют государственную меру,
> привязывающую крестьян к земле независимо от их личного отношения к
> землевладельцу или, точнее, подчиняющую это отношение поземельному
> прикреплению; **под крепостным правом разумеют право человека на
> личность другого, основанное первоначально, при самом его зарождении, на
> частном юридическом акте, на крепости, независимо от отношения
> крепостного к земле, — право, отдававшее крепостного человека, по
> выражению нашего Свода законов, «в частную власть и обладание»
> господина.**

Положение о **поземельном прикреплении крестьян** это предшественник **КРЕПОСТНОГО ПРАВА**, но, это разные термины, однако, очевидно, что этимологически крепостное право вышло из "прикрепления...", а никак не образовалось как-то отдельно и внезапно.

Насчет крепости ума 5-классников: крепость - это не средневековый замок, и это было понятно давно, вспомните Пушкина "Капитанскую дочку" Пушкина, как так описывается крепость. Гринев думал что это именно замок (хотя, он и не был пятиклассником), но крепость оказалось деревушкой обнесенной частоколом и огороженной рвом. То есть крепость - это опорный пункт, то что держит данную область, скрепляет, прикрепляет её к государственным владениям. Швабрина в крепости посадили под замок, но не в темницу замка бросили, а просто заперли в какой-то комнате в деревенском доме. Так что пятиклассник сможет узнать, что из себя представляет крепость, и чем она отличается от замка, но это будет только когда он будет учится в 7 классе и читать литературу.

Ну и насчет терминов - термины это абсолютно не самостоятельные слова, возьмите любой термин, у него будет очень скудный набор значений, но все они связаны с каким-то расхожим корнем. Почему? Потому что язык живет сам по себе, а термины создают. Кстати говоря, вполне вероятно, что КРЕП связано со словом create ну и индоевропейским корнем ker - жар, огонь, потому что:
«ТВЕРЖА-«укрепление, крепость» (Фасмер)
А от твержа связана с творить ~ create.
НУ и всякие "огонь животворящий", мифы про огонь сюда же.

Итого: **креп+и+ть/креп+к+ий -> с+креп+л+ять -> с+креп+а / креп+ость / при+креп+л+ять к земле -> креп+ост+н+ая грамота (даваемая холопам) -> креп+ост+н+ой (в смысле не холоп, но прикрепленный к земле) -> за+креп+ост+ить**

То есть, есть два параллельных повода называть КРЕПОСТНОЙ - потому что крепость-грамота(крепостная грамота, грамота крепости) с происхождением от скрепа, и потому что есть "прикреплять к земле", но оба повода связаны со словами крепить/крепкий. Потому что язык формируется не через поводы, а через понимание связей.

Comment: Из Сети: "Крепостной – этот тот, кого посадили в крепость и закрыли". (Ответ ученика 5 класса.) Поэтому корень там КРЕПОСТ- КРЕПОСТЬ, -и; ж. В России с 11 в. до 1861 г.: крепостная зависимость, крепостное право. // Документ о купле и продаже недвижимого имущества. К. на имение. ◊ Купчая крепость (см. Купчий). <Крепостной, -ая, -ое. К. акт. Но слово устарело, в современном словообразовании не участвует. Или вы хотите словообразовательную цепочку заново переосмыслить?  А если просто узнавать знакомые корни, то будет корень КРЕП. В общем,  выбор: КРЕП или КРЕПОСТН- (непроизв. слово крепостной).

Comment: Понятия вторичны, первичны глаголы или состояния: крепкий, крепить -> крепость, жалко, жаль -> жалость. Производные от понятий это современное явление, возникшее вот вот, 19 век и далее. В 11 веке не было никакой крепостной зависимости, крепостная зависимость появилась после Ивана Грозного, но юридически получила название только в 16 веке, как и пишет Ключевский. Вот тогда появился термин крепость крестьян. "Датой возникновения крепостного права принято считать 1648 год, когда Соборное Уложение полностью прикрепило крестьян к земле, введя бессрочный сыск беглых крестьян."

Comment: Крепость - это юр термин для названия "крестьян прикрепленных к земле". Естественно не в прямом смысле прикрепленных, но по понятиям, они не могли уйти с земли - Юрьев День(дни) отменили. Никак не наоборот.

Comment: Насчет школьника, ну бывает, но в чём-то он прав, но проблема в том, что у 5-классников не развито абстрактное мышление, а значит они понятий не могут понять, тем более юр терминов. Так что это нормально. Но ориентироваться на сказанное пятиклассником в этих вопросах я бы не стал, однако, он прав в том, что слова однокоренные, как ни крути. А значение - это уже надстройка, а не базис.

Comment: Мне кажется, что сначала в языке появился термин "КУПЧАЯ КРЕПОСТЬ" на имущество. (Он сохранялся очень долго.) Когда крестьян приравняли к имуществу по такой купчей крепости, то их стали НАЗЫВАТЬ крепостными. Но это надо уточнять и по истории государства, и по истории языка.  Когда термин "крепостной" появился в языке и был зафиксирован словарями?  В истории тоже точность нужна.

Answer (score 0):

**О словаре  З.А. Потихи** ( к вопросу о выборе словаря)

**[Из Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0,_%D0%97%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)**

**Зиновий Аронович Потиха.** Советский филолог-русист, кандидат филологических наук, доктор педагогических наук, автор работ по русскому языку и словообразованию, профессор Волгоградского государственного педагогического института. Родился: 20 июля 1912 г. Умер: 1987 г. (75 лет)

В 1972 году Зиновий Аронович защитил докторскую диссертацию на тему: **«Лингвистические основы изучения русского словообразования в школе»**[5] и получил учёную степень **доктора педагогических наук.**

З.А. Потиха стал автором **трудов по словообразованию** русского языка, среди которых как словари, так и учебно-методические материалы и пособия для учителей. **В 1986 году** он завершил педагогическую деятельность в ВГПИ.

**[Из статьи](https://naukarus.com/uroki-z-a-potihi-k-100-letiyu-so-dnya-rozhdeniya-uchenogo)**  «Уроки 3. А. Потихи (К 100-летию со дня рождения ученого)»

При морфемном анализе 3. А. Потиха призывал стремиться к **осмысленному и доказательному** разбору слова, исходя из его современного состояния. «"золотым правилом" морфемного анализа, — писал он, — является **сопоставление** однокоренных (и одноструктурных) слов. В диссертации 3. А. Потиха подчеркивал важнейшее методическое требование: «Целесообразно в школе к словообразовательному анализу привлекать лишь **бесспорные** примеры, в которых словообразовательные связи **прозрачны**».

Новизной докторского диссертационного исследования 3. А. Потихи является формулирование и анализ **трех специфических принципов** методики изучения словообразования в школе: во-первых, опора на историзм (диахронический принцип); во-вторых, опора на сопоставление синтеза и анализа слов; в-третьих, опора на мотивированность при анализе **производных слов.**

Автор определил ряд задач изучения раздела «Словообразование в школе», не утративших значения для методики преподавания русского языка начала XXI в.:
«а) выработать у учащихся навык быстро и правильно анализировать слова;

б) научить правильно определять соотношение и взаимодействие морфем в слове как части и целого;

в) научить правильно определять продуктивные **модели**, по которым создаются новые слова;

г) научить вскрывать взаимосвязь **словообразования** и других разделов языкознания - лексики, орфографии, стилистики, грамматики (фонетики, морфологии, а также синтаксиса);

д) научить учащихся видеть не разрозненные факты структуры слова, а цельную закономерную словообразовательную **систему**, входящую в общую систему языка, где все компоненты связаны и взаимодействуют».

Отсюда очевидно, что у школьников должно вырабатываться понимание **системности** русского словообразования.

3. А. Потиха на конкретных примерах продемонстрировал возможности развития способностей учащихся при изучении словообразования в школе.

**Вывод** (по статье).  Итак, 3. А. Потиха завершил свою деятельность в 1986 году, когда **формально-структурный**  анализ  (выделение узнаваемых в современном языке морфем) был **ведущим принципом**. В то же время он придавал большое значение **словообразовательному анализу**, так что не исключено, что он мог бы в новых изданиях своего словаря перейти на **формально-семантический** принцип (с учетом словообразовательных связей).

**Словари**

Потиха З.А. Строение русского слова : Учеб. словарь для зарубеж. школ. — М.: Рус. яз, 1981. — 319 с.

Потиха З.А. Школьный словообразовательный словарь : [Около 25000 слов]. — Волгоград: Кн. изд-во, 1961. — 363 с.

Потиха З.А. Школьный словарь строения слов русского языка : Пособие для учащихся. — М.: Просвещение, 1999. — 318 с

**Приложение**

**[Статья](https://studfile.net/preview/7634279/page:40/)** Методика морфемного, словообразовательного, морфологического разборов.  **https://studfile.net/preview/7634279/page:40/**

Возможны два противоположных подхода к морфемному членению слова: **формально-структурный и формально-семантический.** …Таким образом, **три комплекса** в вопросе о принципах морфемного членения занимают принципиально **разную позицию**: максимально семантизированную и опирающуюся на словообразовательный разбор в комплексе 3, промежуточно в комплексе 1 и формально-структурную, предлагающую практически **субморфное** членение слова в комплексе 2. (Субморфы тождественны морфам данного языка, но только **по форме**; значения они не имеют.)

Comment: Я все-таки склоняюсь к тому, что корень-этимон и корень-морфема - это разные понятия, причем последнее за уши притянутое,  так как лишено историзма и несет ряд узких значений функциональной речи. Функциональная речь не самодостаточная, поэтому морфемный корень - это выдумка социальной инженерии.

Comment: Модели при изучении любого предмета могут быть разные: есть морфемика, а есть этимология. Морфемика — целая наука (сегодня в шкафу откопала учебное пособие  «Морфемика» для студентов и преподавателей и филфака). Там, например, рассматривается  история происхождения аффиксов. А еще сообщается, что термин «морфема» был введен  И.А. Бодуэн де Куртенэ в конце 19 века.  Ученый считал это понятие родовым, объединяющим  корни, аффиксы, префиксы, окончания (как дерево объединяет дуб, березу, ель), странно было бы считать его лишним.

Comment: Что касается школы, то Потиха писал:  «целесообразно в школе к словообразовательному анализу привлекать лишь бесспорные примеры, в которых словообразовательные связи прозрачны».  То есть этимоны для школьного анализа в любом случае не подойдут. А «прозрачным» в этой теме будет корень креп-, то есть это узнаваемый в языке корень. Но разбор: креп-ост-н-ой — субморфное членение,  его вообще нет в словарях. И почему морфемный корень — выдумка социальной инженерии?

Comment: Потому что выдумывают значения понятиям и понятия. Потому что в 19 и особенно 20 веке стали думать над тем, как ограничить язык и тем самым мышление определенных групп людей, как ограничить информацию. Придумали что базой будет понятие, если понятие пересечь не так как оно пересекается или оборвать связи, то будет сложно восстановить логику словообразование и мысли соответственно. Если раньше пытались отталкиваться от создания и усложнения понятия, то теперь не парятся, а просто присваивают словобуквенным наборам значения, создавая мемы и оперируют мемами.

Comment: @Sharon Ничего не понимаю в корнях... Я, собственно, о начале Вашего ответа: "**О словаре З.А. Потиха** ( к вопросу о выборе словаря)". Разве фамилия *Потиха* не склоняется?

Comment: По задумке казалось, что сделают язык для простых людей, а для ученых будет свой и логика, но по факту пошла тотальная деградация языка. Почему-то люди перестают воспринимать слово, мемы запоминаются легче. Плюс эти технологии связаны с восприятием, вот есть лекции по теории музыки на ютубе, там композитор-теоретик девушка говорит каким образом создаются поп песни. И это отлаженная технология связанная с особенностями восприятия музыки, композитор профессионал может сделать так, чтобы "фраза заедала в голове", запоминалась, не потому что в ней смысла много, а потому что это искусство

Comment: Искусственно сделано. Так вот. То что находится в вашей памяти, то что отпечатано в большинстве современных словарей - это искусственно созданные вещи. У Даля тоже был момент искусственности, но тем не менее у него огромное количество сырого материала, в виде басен, фраз, жизненных, а не искусственных. Анна Виленская, можете послушать, про музыку и про популярные песни 90 и по наше время. Попса - это чисто западная технология, это тексты написанные так и музыка написанная так, чтобы она запоминалась и заедала, воздействуя на эмоциональную сферу..

Comment: И вся эта семантика также нужна, чтобы пропихнуть идеологию и сленг. Сленг - это слова, смысл которых разорван с этимоном, в виду того, что это или аббревиатуры, или обрубцы, причем часто еще исковерканные, переиначенные. Любое современное слово - БЛОГ, WeB+log - аббревиатура, причем не по первой литере, а по последней от первого слова. И это называется словообразованием.

Comment: Так вот, но одно дело, когда тебе в этот музыкально-эмоциональный момент вкладывается в мозг что-то высокое, а другое, когда эту паузу заполняет реклама или еще какая-нибудь чепуха. Ну и плюс понятия разрушаются, крепость уже не многозначное, а крепость - это замок, а замок это castle. Грамматика упрощается до чужеродного языка, перестаем склонять слова и тд, в итоге скоро будем говорить все на рунглише, а думать будем вообще как неизвестно кто, биомасса, а тексты будет писать нейросетка, через англоязычные шаблоны, переводя слова через стандартизированные словари, где friend = друг.

Comment: girlfriend - это подруга, а подруга - это сексуальный партнер - sexual partner. И это даже не бейсик инглиш, это бейсик суржик.

Comment: И музыка - это одно из направлений, или метод воздействия, не единственное, семантика тут тоже, словари стандартизированные... воздействие через разрыв связей слова с этимоном и построение новых через эмоционально-мемичные ассоциации. перепрограммирование сознания индивида через формирования метапонятий в языке, путем разрушения классических понятий и прочая деформация языка - это и есть социальная инженерия, одно из её ключевых направлений.

Comment: Но это все лирика, а логика рассуждения звучит так. Вот есть этимология - слово не только в историко-культурной ретроспективе, а вообще некая связь понятий вне времени. Его разрушают, зачем? К чему это ведет. Ну вот крепостной некий отдельный корень крепостн - зачем, для чего? Корень который не связан ни с некой версией скреп - законов определенного периода, ни с привязкой к земле крестьян и невозможности их ухода, ни с правовым жаргоном вроде слова креп. Какой в этом смысл? Не значение, а смысл. Думаю вы понимаете разницу между словами значение и смысл? С чем связано это значение?

Answer (score -1):

**ОТВЕТ**

***Крепостной —*** закрепостить, закрепощать, закрепощение. Все эти слова образованы от «крепостной», поэтому при определении корня проверкой считаются не всегда.

***Корень*** – это **общая** часть родственных слов. Так определяется корень в младших классах,  и таким же определением пользуются старшие школьники в **упрощенной** учебной программе.

Но ведь словообразовательную цепочку можно увидеть так: *крепкий – крепить – крепость – крепостной – закрепостить.* И тогда мы выделим общий корень ***креп-.*** Однако Потиха выделяет корень ***крепост-***, а Тихонов корень ***крепостн-***. Кто же из них прав?

В конечном итоге можно сказать: словари соответствуют **разным** принципам анализа (формальному как более простому и словообразовательному). И учитель должен **указать** ученику, какому словарю соответствует профиль школы и какой он сам рекомендует для разбора. Тогда ни у кого не будет вопросов.

А далее попробуем разобраться со словообразованием как таковым.

1. Слово *закрепостить* появилось в языке тогда же, когда и слова *крепостной*: ***Закрепостить***/закрепощать — это сделать крепостным: ***крепостн/ой*** - за/крепост/и/ть (**усечение основы на Н**), сравнить: медл/енн/ый — за/медл/и/ть, глубокий — за/глуб/и/ть. Формант ***ЗА...И***, приставочно-суффиксальный способ образования.

Поэтому нужно работать со словом ***«крепостной»,*** а это **непроизводное** слово, что видно по **толковым** словарям.  В толковом словаре у него **собственная статья**, где сказано: слово имеет отношение **к общественному строю**, при котором помещик распоряжался личностью, трудом и имуществом принадлежавшего ему крестьянина.

2. Имеет ли слово "крепостной" отношение к слову ***"крепость"***? В современном языке это прежде всего **укрепленный пункт,** но есть еще **специальное (устар.)** значение:  Документ о купле и продаже недвижимого имущества. К. на имение.

И вот когда крестьян стали продавать **как имущество** и включать в **купчую крепость**, то они стали называться крепостными.

3. Но нам знакомо слово "крепость", оно **узнаваемое**, поэтому есть желание выделить корень ***крепост-***. С другой стороны, корень ***креп-*** нам тоже хорошо знаком. **Так как же быть?**
4. В словаре **Тихонова** выделяется корень ***крепостн-*** , то есть это разбор с точным указанием словообразовательных связей. В словаре **Потиха** выделен корень ***крепост-*** (не креп-), то есть **частично** здесь учитывается словообразование, но учитывается не полностью.
5. Как решается задача в школе? Это зависит **от учебного комплекса,** по которому работает учебное заведение. Материал на эту тему приведен в моем первом ответе.

*Таким образом, **три комплекса** в вопросе о принципах морфемного членения занимают принципиально разную позицию: максимально семантизированную и опирающуюся на словообразовательный разбор **в комплексе 3,** промежуточно в **комплексе 1** и формально-структурную, предлагающую практически субморфное членение слова **в комплексе 2**. (Субморфы тождественны морфам данного языка, но только по форме; значения они не имеют.)*

**Как я думаю**, в словаре **Потиха** словообразовательный разбор учитывается частично, а это комплекс 1. Словарь **Тихонова** соответствует комплексу 3.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.** Интересная позиция по школе **у Грамоты.ру.**   По разбору слова и словарям очень много примерно таких же вопросов: учитель **исправил ответ** безо всяких объяснений.  Справка все свои ответы дает по словарю **Тихонова** («он нам ближе»), а  в этих случаях говорится так: ученик должен **указать словарь**, по которому он сделал разбор, тогда к нему **нет претензий**. Может, тогда учитель **назовет словарь**, которому соответствует профиль школы и который он сам рекомендует.

**Приложение**

Материалы из толкового словаря **Кузнецова** на сайте Грамота.ру:

**ЗАКРЕПОСТИТЬ**,  св. кого-что. 1. Подчинить своему влиянию, своей воле, поставить в зависимое положение; поработить. 2. Ист. Сделать крепостным. <Закрепощать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Закрепощаться, -ается; страд. Закрепощение, -я; ср.

**КРЕПОСТНОЙ**, -ая, -ое. Ист. 1. Относящийся к общественному строю, при котором помещик распоряжался личностью, трудом и имуществом принадлежавшего ему крестьянина. К-ые отношения. К-ая зависимость (в России с 11 в. до 1861 г.: личная, земельная, административная и судебная зависимость крестьян от помещика; крепостное право). К. труд. К-ые порядки. К-ое право (форма феодальной зависимости крестьян: прикрепление к земле, административное и судебное подчинение власти землевладельца). 2. Принадлежащий помещику на основе права, действующего при таком общественном строе (о крестьянах, выходцах из крестьян). К-ые крестьяне. К-ая актриса.

**КРЕПОСТЬ**, -и; ж. Укреплённый пункт, подготовленный к круговой обороне и длительной борьбе в условиях осады. Средневековая к. Петропавловская к. Старинные крепости. Оборона крепости. Сдать к. врагу. Комендант крепости. Защищать к. Неприступная к. <Крепостца, -ы; ж. Уменьш. Служить в небольшой крепостце. Крепостной, -ая, -ое. К. ров. К. вал. К-ые башни. К-ая артиллерия. К-ые стены.

**КРЕПОСТЬ**, -и; ж. В России с 11 в. до 1861 г.: **крепостная зависимость,** крепостное право. // **Документ о купле и продаже** недвижимого имущества. К. на имение. ◊ Купчая крепость (см. Купчий). <**Крепостной**, -ая, -ое. К. акт.

**КУПЧИЙ,** -ая, -ее. ◊ **Купчая крепость**. Устар. Нотариальный договор о купле и продаже недвижимого имущества, а также о праве на владение им. Совершить купчую.

**Купчая крепость** — в дореволюционной России **договор купли-продажи** недвижимости, оформленный в нотариальном порядке. К. к. составлялась на гербовой бумаге или оплачивалась гербовыми марками. В XV — XVI вв. наиболее важные договоры **скреплялись** представителями власти путем записи в особую книгу отсюда происходит название ***крепость.***

**[Купчая крепость](https://economy-ru.info/info/40026/)**

**[Крепостное право на Руси: история возникновения и отмены](https://artofconquest.ru/krepostnoe-pravo-na-rusi-istoriya-i-okoncanie)**

Comment: **Комментарий к одному из ответов в этой теме.** **Sharon**: > Второй ответ
> > 1. ***Крепостной*** — закрепостить, закрепощать, закрепощение. Все эти слова образованы от «крепостной», поэтому при определении корня
> проверкой быть не могут. Если пользоваться такой логикой, то тогда практически ни у одного из исходных слов словообразовательных гнёзд определить корень будет невозможно, ибо эти слова просто с чем будет сравнивать: ведь все остальные слова в гнезде образованы именно от этого исходного слова. К примеру, как найти корень в слове ***играть***? С какими родственными словами его можно

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста,  вопрос . Ваш ответ ответом  не является. Предложите свою ВЕРСИЮ  по разбору слова крепостной и доказывайте ее.  А ваше мнение об ответе  Sharon  можно использовать в процессе доказательства.  И немного о ЛОГИКЕ.  А у меня нет "своей логики", а в области грамматики я использую только словари и учебники. Свою ж "логику" нам предлагают другие участники, вам бы с ней разобраться. Кстати, вы мне напомнили кое-что. Один из участников тоже двавл такие ответы и был-таки моим персональным критиком.  Мне лестно, конечно, такое внимание, но иногда оно утомляет.

Comment: «_И немного о ЛОГИКЕ. А у меня нет "своей логики", а в области грамматики я использую только словари и учебники_». === Sharon, НИ В ОДНОМ словаре или учебнике не найдётся вот этого: «_Все эти слова образованы от <…>, поэтому при определении корня проверкой быть не могут_».  Авторство ЭТОГО принадлежит именно Вам. Ну а чтобы какой-либо из школьников не использовал ЭТО в своих разборах, прочитав Ваш ответ, вынужден был **громко** прокомментировать его. Ну а мой вариант разбора слова _крепостной_  вряд ли будет сильно отличаться от разбора, предложенного Ajgy. Будет время – приведу…

Comment: Я полагаю, что вопрос о логике Sharon все-таки лучше задать на форуме и обсудить его с участниками, которым это тоже будет интересно. Мне уже неинтересно, сколько можно заниматься этой темой.  Но мерси за ваше замечание, я немного ИСПРАВИЛА вступление к ответу, чтобы было ПОНЯТНЕЕ (теперь уж школьники ничего не прочитают). И вот им я бы как раз не рекомендовала первый ответ, где так неуважительно и некорректно  выражено отношение к словарю Тихонова. А ведь именно по нему дает ответы Грамота.ру,  или эти ответы тоже нехороши для школьников.

Comment: @Слава Верно подмечено. Тихонов сам не понимал, что делал. В том же "играть" у него суффикс "а", хотя слово непроизводное. Как же так? Ни от чего не образовалось, но корень выделяем "игр"? Не потому ли, что сравниваем с другими словами? В эту же модель пойдут "зевать", "хозяин" и многие другие...